# I wonder is histogram is appropriate for this kind of data and how to make graph in R Studio that i want

Tags: r, statistics

Hi ~ I'm try to make graph which has sample mean on x-axis and

relative frequency(?) on y-axis

to make sure i will give example!

for example when i pick **1sample** from c(1,2,3,4,5)

the possible result will be 1 and 2 and 3 and 4 and5
in that case the relative frequency is 1/5 each !!

so in this case my graph will show 1,2,3,4,5 on x-axis
0.2 for y -axis (because they are same in 1/5)

and if i pick **2sample** from c(1,2,3,4,5) case would be
(1,2) and (1,3), (1,4), (1,5) (2,3)..... and so on (total 10cases)

so sample mean would be (1+2)/2=1.5 .. (1+3)/2=2 .... etc

so in this case x value will be 1.5, 2 ... etc and y value will
1/10 1/10 ...

so, My question is, is histogram is appropriate for this graph??
i want to plot which have sample mean on x -axis, relative frequency on y-axis
and make a line that connect a dot

sorry for too long question
thanks for reading!!

Comment: perhaps a density plot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's entirely appropriate to plot a histogram of sample means. This is an example of a sampling distribution.

To do this, you would create an object that contains the sample means, and then just plot a histogram of that object as you would with any other histogram.  The value of the sample means would be on the x axis, and frequency or relative frequency on the y axis.  You would have to choose an appropriate bin number and breaks vector for your purpose, but it's the same as any other histogram.

Comment: thanks for your answer ~ can you tell me how can i plot  mean of sample on x-axis and relative frequency on y-axis as dot??? as you know, histogram only show us range ..!